# Matrix Multiplication with threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I want to multiplication matrix.When I use Parallel.For,single thread is slower than multi thread.But when I use two threads, single thread is faster than two threads.
I want to multiplication matrix with use two threads. What is my error ? I don't understand.  Thank you for your answers..

```
 class carp
 {
     double[,] a = new double[300, 300];
     double[,] b = new double[300, 300];
     double[,] c = new double[300, 300];
     int indis = 0;

     public carp(double[,] a, double[,] b, double[,] c,int i)
     {
         this.a = a;
         this.b = b;
         this.c = c;
         indis = i;
     }
     public void matrixloop()
     {
         Thread t1;
         Thread t2;
         ThreadStart starter;
         ThreadStart starter2;
         int s = a.GetLength(0);
         for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
         {
             for (int j = 0; j < s; j++)
             {

                starter = () => carpı(i,s,j);
                 starter2 = () => carpı(i, s, j+1);

               t1=new Thread(starter);
                 t2 = new Thread(starter);                        
                 t1.Start();
                 t2.Start();
                 t1.Join();
                 t2.Join();
                 j = j + 1;                     

             }
         }            
     }

     private void carpı(int i, int s, int j)
     {
         //multiplication operation
         double v = 0;

         for (int k = 0; k < s; k++)
         {
             v += a[i, k] * b[k, j];
         }

         c[i, j] = v + 1;            
     }        
 }
```

Comment: Share the code you used to measure both of them. Btw answer is simple your code has to create 2 new threads for each iteration(which is very expensive), where as `Paralell.For` reuses the thread.

Comment: I don't want to use Parallel.For because I want to control myself threads. .How to make this ?.

Comment: It's not clear what kind of answer you expect? What do you meant by *How to make this?* Make what?

Comment: I want to write my thread like java

Comment: You already have your thread created. I don't understand what's your question here. If the question is *Why `Paralell.For` is faster than yours?* I've answered it already [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129420/matrix-multiplication-with-threads#comment42758330_27129420) in my first comment.

Comment: Any kind of mulitthreading needs some kind of workload to spread over the threads; you will need a lot of multiplications to make the overhead of creating multiple taks pay!

Comment: If at all you're interested in reinventing the `Paralell.For`, I recommend [Joe's book](http://www.amazon.com/Concurrent-Programming-Windows-Joe-Duffy/dp/032143482X). Refer *Chapter 13 Data and Task Parallelism.*

Comment: İ did not explain myself.but I understand you.I want to my project has two threads.first thread first line multiplication.second thread second line multiplication at same time.I want to two threads is faster one thread.i hope you understand me

Comment: You have probably a bug; `t2 = new Thread(starter);` must probably be `t2 = new Thread(starter2);`. The 2 after `starter` is missing.

Comment: I don't understand `c[i, j] = v + 1;`. Proper multiplication does not have the `+1`.

Comment: If you want faster calculation then convert the `double[,]` to `C`-style flat array `double[]` or a jagged array `double[][]`. Threading has way too much overhead unless the matrices are huge, and then you are _much_ better off using a sparse matrix library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you want using two `BackgroundWorker` objects

```
public class MatrixCalc
{
    readonly double[,] a, b, c;
    readonly int a_rows, a_cols, b_rows, b_cols, c_rows, c_cols;
    bool result_ok;
    int thread_count;
    BackgroundWorker bw1, bw2;
    AutoResetEvent re;

    public MatrixCalc(double[,] a, double[,] b, double[,] c)
    {
        a_rows=a.GetLength(0);
        a_cols=a.GetLength(1);
        b_rows=b.GetLength(0);
        b_cols=b.GetLength(1);
        c_rows=c.GetLength(0);
        c_cols=c.GetLength(1);
        // keep references of arrays
        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;
        this.c=c;
    }

    public void Multiply()
    {
        result_ok=false;
        this.bw1=new BackgroundWorker();
        this.bw2=new BackgroundWorker();
        this.re=new AutoResetEvent(false);
        bw1.WorkerSupportsCancellation=true;
        bw1.DoWork+=new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);            
        bw1.RunWorkerCompleted+=new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
        bw1.RunWorkerAsync(0);
        bw2.WorkerSupportsCancellation=true;
        bw2.DoWork+=new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        bw2.RunWorkerCompleted+=new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
        bw2.RunWorkerAsync(1);
        re.WaitOne();
        re.WaitOne();
    }
    public bool OK { get { return result_ok; } }
    public void Cancel()
    {
        bw1.CancelAsync();
        bw2.CancelAsync();
        re.WaitOne();
        re.WaitOne();
    }

    void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        thread_count--;
        this.result_ok=(!e.Cancelled)&&(thread_count==0);
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        thread_count++;
        if(!e.Cancel)
        {
            var offset=(int)e.Argument;
            for(int i=0; i<a_rows; ++i)
            {
                // This is the trick. Start from column 0 or 1
                // and skip over one column.
                //
                // Thread 1 Columns : 0,2,4,6,...
                // Thread 2 Columns:  1,3,5,7,...
                //
                for(int j=offset; j<b_cols; ++j, ++j)
                {
                    var sum =InnerLoop(i, j);
                    lock(c)
                    {
                        c[i, j]=sum;
                    }
                    // Debug.WriteLine("C[{0},{1}]={2}", i, j, sum);
                }
            }
        }
        re.Set();
    }

    public double InnerLoop(int a_row, int b_col)
    {
        double sum=0;
        for(int i=0; i<a_cols; i++)
        {
            sum+=a[a_row, i]*b[i, b_col];
        }
        return sum;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int N=5;
        double[,] a = new double[N,N], b=new double[N,N], c=new double[N,N];
        MatrixCalc calc=new MatrixCalc(a, b, c);
        // Fill in some values into arrays
        for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            a[i, i]=1;
            b[i, i]=1;
            if(i>0)
            {
                b[i, 0]=-i;
                a[0, i]=i;
            }
        }

        calc.Multiply();

        // Debug.WriteLine("Result: {0}", calc.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this fails to wait sufficient time somehow. Lets just say the above is for educational purposes only!